# add column in slave db using pt-online-schema-change caused dropped rows

Tags: mysql, database, percona

We wanted to add extra columns in slave database for data reporting purpose with little downtime. So we used pt-online-schema-change to run alter statements on the slave. Throughout this process, there are lots of activity on master db that should replicate to slave db.

However, this broke replication because replication is trying to update a row that does not exist in slave. Then I found out that for one table, during the pt-online-schema-change, around 50% of rows are not copied over to slave from master. The dropping of rows are random. Before this operation, replication was working perfectly.

Another table in the slave also going through the process has one extra row than master because I guess a delete event was not persisted correctly on slave.

I am trying to understand why running pt-online-schema-change on slave does not work. In theory it should. Are there configurations I need to set to make it work? Or is it just not possible to do it. It is surprising that mysql replication would drop rows without raising error until an update on non-existing row happens.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
Something to note is that I used a really high critical-load value. When I didn't specify that, pt-online-schema-change dies due to threads_running running high occasionally.

```
pt-online-schema-change --critical-load "Threads_running=1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of a case where pt-online-schema-change failed to copy 50% of the rows. The only bug related to losing data is this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1246754 which involves adding a primary key constraint to a column that contained duplicate values.

IMHO, I wouldn't recommend adding more columns to a table on the replica anyway. It could cause replication to break in multiple ways if a statement or row event doesn't have the same number of columns.

I'd create a second table on the replica with a 1-to-1 mapping to rows in the replicated table. Store your reporting data in the second table.

Comment: I think if the slave db has extra columns at the end of the table, replication can still work. I am aware that column order matters. If I create a second table on slave, i still need to copy data over from one to the other, defeating the purpose of having a slave in the first place. The slave is purely used to store extra values on each row.

Comment: @benzhang, that's correct, extra columns (or missing columns, one or the other) on the slave are valid configurations in MySQL as long as the discrepancy is strictly at the right side of the table, and, if extra columns, the extra columns are nullable... and no unique or foreign keys are different, or involved in the extra columns.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, but that can still cause problems if you use statement-based replication and you do things like `INSERT INTO table VALUES (...)`, or `INSERT INTO othertable SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: @BillKarwin, true.  I should have mentioned that.  Statement-based replication, yuck.

Comment: We are doing row-based replication. My main question is here is about pt-online-schema-change causing random rows to be dropped. Could my very high critical-load option make things worse?

Comment: Could be. It'd probably be safer to STOP SLAVE, do the ALTER TABLE in the conventional way, and then START SLAVE and let it catch up.